# Zoom Controls for ImageSwitcher in Android 1.6?

Tags: android, image, zooming, imageview

I wish to do the Image Switcher's Touch Event. That is when i touch it, it should wake up the zoom controls. After zoomed in, the image can able the touch scroll on the image up and down. how to do it? Is there any default zoom controls? If not, tell me your suggestion, idea and also valuable links about this? make a note the Target version is android 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [this](http://www.anddev.org/images_and_photos_zoom_in-out-t265.html) in the past.

Comment: But Image Switcher class does not have the SetBounds method. What can i do for that?